# Gnome shows blank log-in screen

Tags: gnome, login, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome

So, I've been using Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 off and on. Last time I was on the OS, I believe that I did some updates through the terminal, not much more.

So, I started the OS back up again and found that Gnome loaded up, but it doesn't show any user logins, it's just blank(aside from the grey noise background and the top-bar functions such as accessibility options, shutdown options, and the time and date).

I've tried to start into the desktop by using the *startx* command through a console but, although my hard drive activity light shows that it's attempting to load information, I'm just met with a black screen in that console after using the command(no errors or anything).

I'm still a bit of a Linux newbie and I'm not quite sure what's going on here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: gnome 2 or gnome 3?

Comment: I don't think that Ubuntu Gnome offers Gnome 2.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an X11 issue you could try,

deleting your /etc/X11/xorg.conf

you may try it first, please give feedback on this:
http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/how_to_fix_your_computers_graphics_with_dpkg-reconfigure

In either case, backup the file "/etc/X11/xorg.conf" before, if there is one.

If you feel it's related only to gnome config. you could try deleting your gnome config.

GNOME2

Run the following in the terminal or Alt+F2:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

That will do is remove all the GNOME2 configuration settings. Log out, and log back in. You'll be back to a stock desktop.

You can backup before playing around with your settings in the future:

```
mkdir ./.old-gnome-config && mv ./.gnome* ./.old-gnome-config && mv .gconf* ./.old-gnome-config && mv ./.metacity ./.old-gnome-config
```

GNOME3

If your config isn't worth saving run the following:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*
```

Comment: Firstly, before I tried this, I did update the Linux kernel as well as a few other programs to see if that would do anything. This resulted in the login screen looking more proper(although still not functional) but another reboot resulted in a loss of video signal after the first loading splash screen, although I get the proper video signal when in the console.

Comment: I tried both methods and neither worked, unfortunately. Although, I did notice that, in the X11 directory, there was no file specifically named "xorg.conf" but, rather, "xorg.conf.04302015".